# Basic LightBox Effect using CSS and Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve the Basic Lightbox effect using JavaScript.
Well let me inform you, I am a beginner to the JavaScript.

What I want is, when I click on the link, lightbox effect should take over the action.(i..e a Image should be displayed in the centre of the page, with tranperant black colored background)

but some how this effect is not taking place in Google Chrome/Firefox/ even on IE 9

Check my jsfiddle for more details

https://jsfiddle.net/Addle/z58jzydj/12/

here's main JavaScript Code:

```
$(".lightbox").click(function(){
    var overlayLink;
    overlayLink = $(this).attr("href");
    window.startOverlay(overlayLink);
    return false;

    function startOverlay(overlayLink) {
    $("body").append('<div class="overlay"></div><div class="container">    </div>').css({"overflow-y":"hidden"});
    $(".overlay").animate({"opacity":"0.6"}, 200, "linear");
    $(".container").html('<img src="'+overlayLink+'" alt="" />');

    $(".container img").load(function() {
        var imgWidth = $(".container img").width();
        var imgHeight = $(".container img").height();
        $(".container")
            .css({                "top":"50%","left:"50%","width":imgWidth,"height":imgHeight,"margin-top": -(imgHeight/2),"margin-left":-(imgWidth/2)
            })
            .animate({"opacity":"1"}, 200, "linear");
    });

         $(".overlay").click(function(){
    $(".container, .overlay")
    .animate({"opacity":"0"}, 200, linear, function(){
        $(".container, .overlay").remove();
     })
});

}

});
```

Please somebody assist me to point out the exact mistake that I am doing.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are loads of typos in your code

- `.css({"top": "50%","left: "50%","width":`
- You need to include jQuery if you want to use `$`

Please, learn how to use the Browser Javascript console to find bugs instead of just posting half-working code to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you "Johanes Jander" for the precious advice. Use of the Console to debug the error has really helped me, and now after lot of trial and error, I have finally fine tuned my JavaScript code. and this has solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

In `"top":"50%","left:"50%"` you are missing a `"` after `left`. Is `"top":"50%","left":"50%"`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in syntax, formatting, typing mistakes in my JavaScript code.
I have fine tuned it now.
and all my Script is running fine.

and I have added the jquery file to code.
Check the Jsfiddle code for details:

https://jsfiddle.net/Addle/z58jzydj/20/

```
Thanks guys for your help
```